# How can I fix the error: "Cannot POST /users. StatusCode: 404" while making a POST request in Postman?

Tags: post, nestjs

I'm following the [article](https://medium.com/swlh/create-an-api-rest-with-nestjs-1954723e8234) while working on the [project](https://github.com/invzbl3/rest-api-nestjs).

When making a `POST` request in `Postman`:

```
http://localhost:3000/users
```

With `Body` request:

```
{
    "name": "Jose Luis",
    "lastName": "Campos Bautista"
}
```

I'm getting the issue as:

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "Cannot POST /users",
    "error": "Not Found"
}
```

Am I missing something in the steps of the article? Does it the problem related specifically to `API`?

Inside the [controller](https://github.com/invzbl3/rest-api-nestjs/blob/main/src/rest-api-nestjs/src/user/controller/user.controller.ts#L6) I have annotated as `users`:

```
@Controller('users')
```

Before executing a `Postman` request, I run the command:

```
npm run start:dev
```

Also I use the `Postgres` database with the *next format of configuration*:

```
DB_URL=postgres://user:password@localhost:5444/dataBaseName
ENTITY_PATH=dist/**/**/*.entity{.js, .ts}
```

Thanks in advance for any reasonable advice/ideas on how I can overcome this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have looked in your git repo. You should insert some route inside your controller like this

```
@Post('/create')
```

Your service is also lacking `await` before calling the save method in your service. It should be like

```
async create(user: UserDto): Promise<UserDto> {
return await this.userRepository.save(user);
 }
```

and your controller should be like

```
 @Post()
 async create(@Body() user: UserDto): Promise<UserDto> {
 return await this.userService.create(user);
 }
```

You also don't have a connection initialization inside your app.module.ts so your API wouldn't be able to save data inside database.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's helpful. Could you clarify, please, how `connection initialization` should be written, please, in the `app.module.ts` directly? Could you update your answer with any examples of it or share any links if it helps here?

Comment: you can try this link for a full CRUD example https://medium.com/@niyam-muliya/nestjs-and-its-crud-operations-54b5dd7d6195. You can use any database for your app, this example uses postgres.

Answer (score 2):

Your `UserModule` is never registered with the application. The `AppModule` needs to have `UserModule` in its `imports` array. Just because the file exists and is written doesn't mean Nest knows what to do with it. You have to tell the application that the module should be used by having it in the imports path of some module that eventually makes its way back to the root module (usually `AppModule`)

---

Side Note: when you do that, you will get an error from TypeORM because you call `TypeormModule.forFeature()` without ever importing `TypeormModule.forRoot()`, so just a heads up that you need to add that

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. The problem is: if I add `UserModule` with the following import: `import { UserModule } from './rest-api-nestjs/src/user/user.module';`, I'm getting the issue as: `"Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserEntityRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument DataSource at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context."`. If I remove `UserModule` from AppModule, I don't have it, but I can't make the `POST` request, as I mentioned in the question, for some reason. 
Could you clarify, please, where do I need to add `TypeormModule.forFeature()` with import?

Comment: Because, as for now, I have it inside `user.module.ts` [file](https://github.com/invzbl3/rest-api-nestjs/blob/main/src/rest-api-nestjs/src/user/user.module.ts#L8), but it doesn't affect the situation in overall.

Comment: Like I said, you need to add `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()` if you use `TypeOrmModule.forFeature()`. Under thehood, `forRoot()` sets up the TypeORM Datasource object and `forFeature()` uses the `dataSource.getRepository()` method to make the repository an injectable provider. `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()` is usually called in the root module, that would be `AppModule` in this case, and it sets up global providers for the `DataSource` the is created